# Indicate a quintuple $(s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5) \in \Bbb{R}^5$ that is the solution of the first three equations but is not a system solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Find a quintuple $(s_1, s_2, s_3, s_4, s_5) \in \Bbb{R}^5$ that is the solution of the first three equations but is not a system solution
$$
\begin{cases}
x_1+x_2 &=1\\
x_1+x_2+x_3 &=4\\
x_2+x_3+x_4 &=-3\\
x_3+x_4+x_5 &=2\\
x_4+x_5 &=-1
\end{cases}$$

I'm having difficulties solving this exercise because I don't know how to proceed... Could anyone explain to me how should I proceed to solve this exercise succesfully and if this exercise as anything to do with subgroups?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "if this exercise as anything to do with subgroups". What do you mean by "subgroups" in this context?

Answer (score 2):

1. Determine one solution $x_1, x_2, x_3 , x_4$ of the system of the first three equations.
2. Determine now $x_5$ such that $x_3+x_4+x_5 \ne 2$ and $x_4+x_5 \ne -1.$
3. $x_1, x_2, x_3 , x_4, x_5$  will do the job.
4. the exercise has nothing to do with subgroups.

Comment: Thank you Fred for you answer! The question can be a bit "stupid" but I'm still learning...

Comment: +1 for 4.$\,\,$